# Is there a free to use sdf simulation model with working gazebo plugin

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a free robot model (sdf) working with gazebo and ros groovy? Where can I download it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81021/is-there-a-free-to-use-sdf-simulation-model-with-working-gazebo-plugin/) by [Seba](https://answers.ros.org/users/5005/seba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can look at the Gazebo Tutorials for some simple robots, and the [Gazebo DRC Tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials#ROS_Integration) which use [Atlas](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.7/atlas_sim_interface).

---

Originally posted by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) with karma: 174 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0